# Why does this String to date conversion return null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am tring to create a NSDate variable from string object but it is keep giving me nil object, can anyone tell me why,

```
dateFormater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"ccc, dd MMM YYYY h:m:s zzz"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormater dateFromString:@"Wed, 29 May 2013 15:52:38 GMT"];

NSLog(@"date =%@",date);
```

**output:** null.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Ditch the day of the week somehow.  It frequently causes trouble.

Comment: Also, be sure to explicitly set the date formatter locale (to, eg, "en_US_POSIX") or you can get screwed up if the user monkeys with the phone's 12/24 setting.

Comment: okay thanks, what should be the formater for if gmt is in -0700 format

Comment: @Developer if you satisfied my answer so please upvote my answer.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 29 May 2013 15:52:38 GMT";


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```

OR  [check this link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html)

I Hope this code useful for you.

Comment: @iPatel but change your set your setDateFormat:  so get perectly .

Comment: He would set the format properly if he knew the date format patterns. So this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: O thanks, the site i am looking form format had different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

istead of

```
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"ccc, dd MMM YYYY h:m:s zzz"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DateFormat should be `@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormater setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormater dateFromString:@"Wed, 29 May 2013 15:52:38 GMT"];

NSLog(@"date =%@",date);
```